# Find implicit function from

Tags: functions, implicit

I'm trying to find implicit function.
I have four parametric equations for functions

```
T := T[x,y,z]
X := X[x,y,z]
Y := Y[x,y,z]
Z := Z[x,y,z]
```

And I want to find a function $F$ so that

```
F[T,X,Y,Z] == 0
```

So that $F$ is independent of $x,y,z$.

Comment: Try `Eliminate` ! But without runnable code it's difficult to help.

Comment: If they involve only polynomials, try the Grobnerbasis approach

Comment: I will look at that, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a parametric representation of an affine variety (a set of polynomial parametric expressions $F_i=g_i(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n)$, can we find the defining implicit representation $H(g_1,g_2,\cdots,g_n)$?  The answer is yes via a Groebner Basis. And Mathematica has the function GroebnerBasis.  Take for example:

$$
\begin{align}
x&=1+t \\
y&=1+t^2
\end{align}
$$
so that the Groebner Basis is computed as:

```
eqn1 = x - 1 - t;
eqn2 = y - 1 - t^2;
GroebnerBasis[{eqn1, eqn2}, {t, x, y}]

(* {2 - 2 x + x^2 - y, 1 + t - x} *)
```

so that the implicit expression is $H(x,y)=2-2x+x^2-y$.
Another:

```
f1[x_, y_] := 2 x^2
f2[x_, y_] := x^3 y + 4 y^2
f3[x_, y_] := 4 - x y + x^2 y + 2 x^2
gb = GroebnerBasis[{t - f1[x, y], z - f2[x, y], u - f3[x, y]}, {x, y, 
    t, z, u}];
```

In this case the basis consists of 12 polynomials but one will be in terms of t,z, and u only:

```
-131072 - 131072 t - 53248 t^2 - 11264 t^3 - 1312 t^4 - 64 t^5 + 
 6 t^6 + t^7 + 131072 u + 98304 t u + 27648 t^2 u + 3584 t^3 u + 
 208 t^4 u - 4 t^5 u - 2 t^6 u - 49152 u^2 - 24576 t u^2 - 
 3840 t^2 u^2 - 192 t^3 u^2 - 2 t^4 u^2 + t^5 u^2 + 8192 u^3 + 
 2048 t u^3 + 64 t^2 u^3 - 512 u^4 + 2048 t z + 2048 t^2 z + 
 672 t^3 z + 56 t^4 z - 4 t^5 z - 1024 t u z - 768 t^2 u z - 
 136 t^3 u z + 4 t^4 u z + 128 t u^2 z + 64 t^2 u^2 z - 8 t^2 z^2 + 
 8 t^3 z^2 - 2 t^4 z^2
```

There are computation limits on the calculations and the monomial ordering can affect the computation time.